# Heroku Buildpack directory missing after creation in compile step

Tags: heroku, buildpack, pyenchant, enchant

I have a buildpack make to compile enchant dictionaries, and it's having issues having the directory persisting after the dyno deployment.

Below is the relevant snippet.

```
DEFAULT_DIR_ENCHANT_DICTS="/app/.enchant/myspell"
mkdir -p $DEFAULT_DIR_ENCHANT_DICTS
cd /app/.enchant/myspell
echo $PWD
```

I've confirmed that the directory is created during this compile via `cd` since it fails otherwise, and printed it after changing to it. However after deployment, doing `heroku run bash` on the app and then trying to visit the directory shows that it hasn't actually be created.

I suspect this has something to do with heroku being ephemeral, and hence not keeping these changes, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on securing directories from being wipe before deployment.

Interestingly, I create this folder as well:

```
"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/enchant/share/enchant/myspell"
```

which doesn't get wiped, leading me to believe that certain folders don't get wiped; however, enchant requires the files to be in this specific location in order to be detected, since it seems to not detect them via `site-packages` folder currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to create the dir somewhere other than `/app`. That's because when the buildpack runs, it's done in a temp dir. For most purposes the dir you want is `pwd`. You're buildpack might look like this:

```
DEFAULT_DIR_ENCHANT_DICTS="$(pwd)/.enchant/myspell"
mkdir -p $DEFAULT_DIR_ENCHANT_DICTS
cd .enchant/myspell
echo $PWD
```

Comment: That did the trick! logging into with bash has confirmed that the dictionaries are detected. May I ask how you knew to use $(pwd)? The documentation provided by Heroku regarding making your own buildpack are fairly sparse.